# How to implement tungsten replicator BuildAuditTable filter

Tags: database-replication, auditing, tungsten-replicator

This is regarding :

```
com.continuent.tungsten.replicator.filter.BuildAuditTable
```

I tried both Tungsten  2.2 and  3.0

My intial configuration

```
./tools/tpm install alpha \
--topology=master-slave \
--master=host1 \
--replication-user=tungsten \
--replication-password=password \
--install-directory=/opt/continuent \
--members=host1,host2 \
--start
```

Then i tried adding BuildAuditTable filter in the following two ways :

Try 1:

```
 ./tools/tpm update alpha \
 --property='replicator.filter.bidiSlave.auditf=com.continuent.tungsten.replicator.filter.BuildAuditTable' \
 --property='replicator.filter.bidiSlave.auditf.targetTableName=indiaresorts.audit_table' \
 --repl-svc-applier-filters=auditf
```

Try 2 :

```
  ./tools/tpm update alpha \
 --property='replicator.filter.auditf=com.continuent.tungsten.replicator.filter.BuildAuditTable' \
 --property='replicator.filter.auditf.targetTableName=indiaresorts.audit_table' \
 --repl-svc-applier-filters=auditf
```

But both times i got the following error :

```
Error on host2 (slave)
ERROR : 
pendingExceptionMessage: Plugin class name property is missing or null:  key=replicator.filter.auditf
```

Please let me know how i can get through this issue.  Also i had a doubt about the audit table: whether it is automatically created or we have to create it and what its schema will be (column names e.t.c.).

Waiting for your kind response.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a .tpl (template) file prior to `tpm install` in order to define a new property in the `static-{service_name}.properties` configuration file.

1. Create a new directory at `tungsten-replicator/filters` where you extracted the Tungsten tarball.

   Starting from 3.0.0, [this can also be in the directory specified with `--template-search-path`](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/issues/detail?id=907).
2. Add `tungsten-replicator/filters/your_name_of_choice.tpl` containing custom property keys and default values.

   ```
   replicator.filter.custom=com.continuent.tungsten.replicator.filter.JavaScriptFilter
   replicator.filter.custom.script=
   replicator.filter.custom.config=
   ```
3. Install:

   ```
   ./tools/tpm install alpha \
     ...
     --property='replicator.filter.custom.script=path/to/script' \
     --property='replicator.filter.custom.config=path/to/config' \
     --repl-svc-applier-filters=custom
   ```

You can check the service configuration file at `path/to/installation_directory/{service_name}/tungsten/tungsten-replicator/conf/static-{service_name}.properties` on one of the nodes to see if the template file was incorporated.

As for the audit table, a casual glance at the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/tungsten-replicator/source/browse/trunk/replicator/src/java/com/continuent/tungsten/replicator/filter/BuildAuditTable.java) seems to indicate that

- You need to create the table yourself
- The schema is the same as that of the incoming table

Which means either the replication must be restricted to a single table or the audit table must contain all possible columns contained in the database.